# Как запустить внедренный файл в c#?

Tags: c#

Решил побаловаться с кодом в Visual Studio 2019 и поковырять C#. Пытаюсь сделать запуск файла(*.png и .mp4*) из папки **Resources**, но безуспешно. Искал много вариантов, все были написаны ближе к 2015 году и, к сожалению, не сработали.

Вот то что уже есть:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Ошибка здесь. Мне нужно узнать полный путь к Screenshot_2.png через код
            Process.Start("Screenshot_2.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какая версия .NET?

Comment: 4.7.2, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Папка Resources - где? В вашем проекте или скомпилированной версии приложения? Если первое, то вам нужно сначала достать файл из ресурсов, сохранить на диск, и только потом отправлять в шелл.

Comment: Как называется объект в ресурса? `"Screenshot_2.png"` - это имя файла, а объект как называется? `WindowsFormsApp2.Properties.Resources....`

Comment: `WindowsFormsApp2.Properties.Resources.Screenshot_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сначала достать файл из ресурсов и сохранить его в файл, например (предположим, что ресурс имеет тип `Image`)

```cs
string fileName = "Screenshot_2.png";
WindowsFormsApp2.Properties.Resources.Screenshot_2.Save(fileName);
Process process = new Process(fileName);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; // нужно для .NET Core и новее
process.Start();
```

Comment: Сработало вариант с `WindowsFormsApp2.Properties.Resources.Screenshot_2.Save(fileName);`

Comment: @megared ок, подправил ответ.